# Value is lost after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

When ajax compass with the value new prices you can see it it the succes function.

But if you want to see the value under the ajax function `new_prices` is `undefined` ??

How is this possible?

```
var new_prices;

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/spares/admin/getKoersBetweenDate/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "valutaId=" + valutaId + "&datum=" + date_added,
            success: function(response){
                  var new_price = price_ps / response.valuta[0].koers;
                   var total = new_price;
                   new_prices = total;

            }
        });
         console.log(new_prices);
```

Comment: @VickyGonsalves It has, i set it in the succes:  new_prices = total;

Comment: You are trying to log `new_prices` as soon as you trigger the AJAX call, so it will print `undefined`.